# ClassCastException: Cannot cast java.sql.Date (id=9010) to java.sql.Timestamp

Tags: java, date, classcastexception, sqldatetime, sql-timestamp

I am having a problem with a Java 1.4 app.

I am executing a JDBC Qyery-which is 2 date fields in an Oracle database (both the 2 fields I am reading is of type DATE with NULLABLE = false)

```
SELECT effFrom, effTo FROM myTable WHERE ....
```

And is exceuted with a JDBCConnection

```
Object[][] result = JDBCConnection.getSqlObjectArray(query, bindVals);
```

I get the data back in my result and loop through it

```
for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
 java.sql.Timestamp effFrom = (java.sql.Timestamp ) result[i][0];
 java.sql.Timestamp effTo = (java.sql.Timestamp ) result[i][1];
```

but it fails converting the object to a java.sql.Timestamp with the error **ClassCastException: Cannot cast java.sql.Date (id=9010) to java.sql.Timestamp**

```
(java.sql.Timestamp ) result[i][0]
```

So I changed the convertion to

```
java.sql.Date effFrom = (java.sql.Date) result[i][0];
```

And it is working. All perfect.

But the thing is that my code did not change and the data did not change for the last 6 months atleast.

It did work with the Timestamp conversion up to yesterday and today it is not working with the timestamp but with the Date.

I then went back to the source code repo and seen that it was originally java.sql.Date about 2 years ago and now I basically rolled it back. So clearly there is something that I am missing here.

Is there a way that the JDBC query could mis interpret the data type?

As per Rudi's question what is inside JDBCConnection.getSqlObjectArray()

It has a JdbcDaoSupport class called dao

```
 public static Object[][] getSqlObjectArray(String sql, String bind1, String bind2, String bind3) {

        Object[][] a = dao.getSqlObjectArrayImpl(sql, bind1, bind2, bind3);
        return a;
    }
```

Comment: @Chrispie Can please attach table description

Comment: I added the following to my question 
(both the 2 fields I am reading is of type DATE with NULLABLE = false)

Comment: @hfontanez - Did you actually read the question before claiming it's a duplicate?

Comment: It seems to me if we're to be able to help we need to know whats inside `JDBCConnection.getSqlObjectArray()` and which data types your `effFrom` and `effTo` columns are inside your DB.

Comment: Have you changed the jdbc driver?

Comment: @hfontanez I added what is in JDBCConnection.getSqlObjectArray(). There is not much happening there. But it is using sprring 2.5 to to the db call

Comment: @Joachim We are using an oracle 11g DB with ojdbc14.jar driver. This has not been upgraded in the last 2years